# Assigning a webview to a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I was following a tutorial about WKWebViews (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/4/2/creating-a-simple-browser-with-wkwebview) and I wanted to change this line

```
view = webview
```

by

```
view.subviews[0].subviews[0] = webview
```

Because I want the webbrowser to be in that particular view. However, XCode complains about it saying: "Cannot assign through subscript: 'subviews' is a get-only property".

Why does it work with the highest view and it doesn't with the other ones? Is there a way to edit subviews so I can assign the webview to the subview I want? Because I've seen that it is possible to remove subviews so it's not like it's a read-only property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly assign the `readonly` property. Instead of doing this. `view.subviews[0].subviews[0] = webview`

Just add the webviews as subview to your main view.

```
let rootView = view.subviews[0]
rootView.addSubview(webView)
rootView.bringSubview(toFront:webView)
```

Else do the below

```
rootView.insertSubview(webView, at: 0)
```